# Comparing list counts with of two objects C#

Tags: c#, list

I have been sitting with a little problem that Was hoping for some help with.

I have two lists of modules that looks as follow.

What I am basically trying to achieve is track completed topics.

m1 would represent the completed set of modules with its skills and topics, and m2 would represent topics modules, skills and topics that where accessed and that are incomplete.

```
List <ModuleA> m1;
List <ModuleB> m2;
public class ModuleA
{
    public bool completed { get; set; }
    public string ModuleCode { get; set; }
    public List<Skill> lstKeySkills { get; set; }
}
public class ModuleB
{

    public string ModuleCode { get; set; }
    public List<Skill> lstKeySkills { get; set; }
}
public class Skill
{
    public string KeySkillName { get; set; }
    public List<Topic> LstTopics { get; set; }
}
public class Topic
{
    public string TopicName { get; set; }
}
```

How can I do topic count comparisons within the skills of the two modules?

I have tried something like this but it seems very messy and incorrect.

```
foreach (var mc in m1)
{
    foreach (var v in m2)
    {
        if (v.ModuleCode == mc.ModuleCode)
        {
            foreach (var skillsIC in v.lstKeySkills)
            {
                foreach (var skillsC in mc.lstKeySkills)
                {
                    if (skillsIC.LstTopics.Count() == skillsC.LstTopics.Count())
                    {
                        //Count is the same
                    }
                }
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are duplicating a lot of code there. Do you really have two identical `Skill` classes and two identical `Topic` classes? And you could easily have `ModuleA` inherit from `ModuleB` adding just the `completed` property (which ought to be `Completed`)

Comment: So what exactly do you want? Can you provide some sample data and expected output? This is likely going to be solved via Linq. Ignoring the duplicated code as pointed out by Matt.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "topic count comparisons". It would rally help if you could give a short but complete example with data. (And why do you have two sets of classes which are identical?)

Comment: Ive edited out the duplicate declarations - it was not helping readability of the question.

Comment: Do you want to get the distinct number of topics covered by m1 and likewise for m2 and then compare the counts? I'm guessing that some modules might have the same skills and some skills may have the same topics in so the problem is one of getting the distinct list of topics but do correct me if I've missed the point...

Comment: What I am basically trying to achieve is track completed topics.

m1 would represent the completed set of modules with its skills and topics, and m2 would represent the same modules and skills...but with only some topics within the skills accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a join, where the list counts match. Its much easier in LINQ

```
var result = m1.Join(m2, a => a.ModuleCode, b => b.ModuleCode, (a,b) => new { A = a, B = b})
           .Where (x => x.A.lstKeySkills.Count() == x.B.lstKeySkills.Count());
```

In this example, `result` will be an enumerable of anonymous items, which has 2 properties

- `A` is the `ModuleA`
- `B` is the `ModuleB`

`A` and `B` will always match on `ModuleCode` and have the same number of Skills

Answer (score 2):

You can use `join` clause:

```
var result = from a in m1 // ModuleA iterable
             join b in m2 // ModuleB iterable
                 on new { a.ModuleCode, a.Skills.Count }
             equals new { b.ModuleCode, b.Skills.Count }
             select new { a, b };
```